# Как выполнить сравнение полей в запросе к БД? MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Есть коллекция из документов типа:

```
 {field_1: 'val_1', field_2: 'val_2', ..., update: 'no_update'}
```

Я хочу обновлять field_2, только в том случае если test_val !== val_2.

Т.е. это я могу осуществить следующим образом:

```
 let test_val;

 Collection.findOne({field_1: 'val_1'})
 .then(async res => {
     if (res.field_2 !== test_val) {
         return await Collection.updateOne(
                     {field_1: 'val_1'},
                     {field_2: test_val, update: 'update'}
                )
     }
  });
```

Таким образом нужно сравнивать несколько полей в документе.
Возможно ли проводить сравнение и изменять только нужные поля за один запрос к БД?

Comment: `updateOne({field_1: ''val_1", field_2: ''val_1"}, {$set: {field_3: ''val_3"}})`

Comment: @Дмытрык, извините, сразу не полно описал задачу. Мне еще нужно в случае изменения поля, чтобы редактировалось другое поле. Т.е. что бы в документе была информация о том, что некоторые его поля изменены.

Comment: `updateOne({field_1: ''val_1", field_2: ''val_1"}, {$set: {field_3: ''val_3", field_4: ''val_4"}})`

Comment: @Дмытрык, спасибо. Но мне нужно записывать информацию именно о том, что поле было изменено. А так, получается что я просто знаю что оно было перезаписано. Т.е. если поле не изменилось, то нужно 'no_update', а если изменилось, то 'update'

Comment: не очень понимаю. Я думаю, что эта задача более широкая, чем Вы ее себе представляете  и она выходит за рамки этого вопроса. Самое простое, поле сделать объектом и поместить туда соответствующий флаг